# how to emulate keyboard input with JxBrowser

Tags: java, jxbrowser

I'm writting a spider with JxBrowser. How to emulate keyboard input with JxBrowser?

I use this code to input text to element. But it is not emulate keyboard input events.

```
((InputElement) element).value("xxxValue");
```

Comment: can you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate keyboard input in JxBrowser 6.x in the following way: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000091678-forwarding-key-events

As for JxBrowser 7.x, you can input only separate buttons in the following way:

```java
browser.dispatch(KeyPressed.newBuilder(KeyCode.KEY_CODE_A).keyChar('a').build());
browser.dispatch(KeyTyped.newBuilder(KeyCode.KEY_CODE_A).keyChar('a').build());
browser.dispatch(KeyReleased.newBuilder(KeyCode.KEY_CODE_A).build());
```

Unfortunately, the functionality to convert some text in a sequence of key events is absent in JxBrowser.